How to use Count in a Pivot clause
I'm using Oracle 21C.
My query involves three tables that can be created with the following code:
Create Table vol_att
( prim_key integer NOT NULL,
 event_fkey integer,
 contact_fkey integer,
 attendance_type varchar2(256),
 CONSTRAINT vol_att_pk PRIMARY KEY (prim_key)
);
Insert All
   Into vol_att(prim_key, event_fkey, contact_fkey, attendance_type)
   Values(1, 1, 801, 'I')
   Into vol_att(prim_key, event_fkey, contact_fkey, attendance_type)
   Values(2, 1, 234, 'Z')
   Into vol_att(prim_key, event_fkey, contact_fkey, attendance_type)
   Values(3, 2, 258, 'I')
   Into vol_att(prim_key, event_fkey, contact_fkey, attendance_type)
   Values(4, 2, 234, 'Z')
   Select 1 from DUAL;
   
Create Table vol_con
( prim_key integer NOT NULL,
 last_name varchar2(256),
 first_name varchar2(256),
 CONSTRAINT vol_con_pk PRIMARY KEY (prim_key)
);
Insert All
   Into vol_con(prim_key, last_name, first_name)
   Values(234, 'Potter', 'Harry')
   Into vol_con(prim_key, last_name, first_name)
   Values(258, 'Weasley', 'Ron')
   Into vol_con(prim_key, last_name, first_name)
   Values(801, 'Granger', 'Hermione')
   Into vol_con(prim_key, last_name, first_name)
   Values(500, 'Malfoy', 'Draco')
   Select 1 from DUAL;
   
CREATE TABLE vol_evn
( prim_key integer NOT NULL,
 event_date date,
 CONSTRAINT vol_evn_pk PRIMARY KEY (prim_key)
);
Insert All
   Into vol_evn(prim_key, event_date)
   Values(1, to_date('30-mar-2023', 'dd-mon-yyyy'))
   Into vol_evn(prim_key, event_date)
   Values(2, to_date('18-apr-2023', 'dd-mon-yyyy'))
   Select 1 from DUAL;

The following code generates a report
select
    *
from
    (select
        vc.last_name
      , va.attendance_type
      , ve.event_date
    from
        vol_att va
            full outer join vol_evn ve
              on va.event_fkey = ve.prim_key
            full outer join vol_con vc
              on va.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key
    )
pivot (
    max(attendance_type) for event_date in 
        (to_date('2023-03-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') Mar_30_2023, 
         to_date('2023-04-18', 'yyyy-mm-dd') Apr_18_2023
        )
      )
order by
    last_name;

The above code produces expected results that look like:



LAST_NAME
MAR_30_2023
APR_18_2023




Granger
I
(null)


Malfoy
(null)
(null)


Potter
Z
Z


Weasley
(null)
I



I'd like to make a new report that would count the attendance (Anything that isn't null).  I'd like the new report to look like:




MAR_30_2023
APR_18_2023





2
2



How can I alter my code so that it produces a report in two rows: The header of dates and the second row containing the counts?
Thanks for looking at this.

You could take out the last_name field, and require that attendance_type is not null. Then pivot, using the count of distinct records from the vol_con table (having last_name) as the data. Because of the constraints, you can replace the full outer joins with an inner join and left outer join respectively:
select *
from
    (select     ve.event_date,
                vc.prim_key
     from       vol_att va
     inner join vol_evn ve 
             on va.event_fkey = ve.prim_key
     left join  vol_con vc
             on va.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key
     where      va.attendance_type is not null
     )
pivot (
     count(distinct prim_key) for event_date in (
         to_date('2023-03-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') Mar_30_2023, 
         to_date('2023-04-18', 'yyyy-mm-dd') Apr_18_2023
     )
);


Thank you very much for responding Trincot.  I probably didn't make myself clear, sorry about that.  The dates (event_date column in vol_evn table) are not static, but will grow over time.  I don't want to add a case statement to the code after every meeting.  My initial thought was adding a COUNT to the attendance_type column in the vol_att table where it was not null.  I'm not sure if that approach is good, or how to do it.  I added the to_dates in the pivot / IN clause but that

Oh but you already need to specify those dates in your pivot query? Why is that then not a problem?

Thank you very much for responding Trincot.  I probably didn't make myself clear, sorry about that.  The dates (event_date column in vol_evn table) are not static, but will grow over time.  I don't want to add a case statement to the code after every meeting.  My initial thought was adding a COUNT to the attendance_type column in the vol_att table where it was not null.  I'm not sure if that approach is good, or how to do it.  I added the to_dates in the pivot / IN clause to illustrate this example.

The full code is in an Apex Classic Report with the source type "PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query".  It starts out with:  declare
l_pivot_cols varchar2(4000);
l_sql        clob := q'{

It ends with }';
begin
select
listagg(apex_string.format('date ''%0'' "%0"', to_char(event_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')), ', ')
within group (order by event_date)
into
l_pivot_cols
from
vol_event;
return apex_string.format(l_sql, l_pivot_cols);
end;

So I reference the dates by the statement:  Pivot (max(attendance_type for event_date in (%s)) order by last_name }';

I rewrote my answer. Maybe that is what you need?

That was it exactly.  Many Thanks trincot !
